# Winding number definition and methods

Tags: complex-analysis

Can somebody recommend a good textbook on complex analysis with an introduction to winding number approach? I studied complex variables but not a complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enjoyed both Lang's book and Ahlfors' book.

Comment: Thank you, I found both books; the explanations are detailed and clear.